# flagship Merchent Account Payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

hello i have to integrate flagship merchant services on my project.But i don't have any idea about this.if any person any idea about this or have any api regarding this please let me know .I have also integrate reoccurring payment service in this.So if any body has worked on this payment express please provide me the api or the flow so i can integrate this as soon as possible
My project is in php so need api in php

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to this [Flagship Merchant Services](http://www.cardservicesales.com/). According to their [FAQ](http://www.flagshipmerchantservices.com/faqs/faqs.htm#q05), you need an Internet merchant account with them before they'll provide you with the First Data Global Gateway API to interface with their payment gateway.

I worked on similiar integration code with a local credit card processing provider and they only provide the interface API only when the client has signed up an account with the provider. Presumably, it's for security purposes (at least security through obscurity)